# JSTL Pagination for foreach loop

Tags: html, jstl

I have been trying to add pagination for JSTl  function but i am not able to achieve it. Here is an exapmple of my code below:

```
<c:forEach items="{items}" var ="item" varstatus="count" begin="1" end="13">
    <div>
         printing some attributes of items;

    </div>
</c:forEach>
<ul>
<li><a href="">1</a><li>
<li><a href="">2</a><li>
<li><a href="">3</a><li>
<li><a href="">4</a><li>
.
.
</ul>
```

Each page should contain 13 items and the length of items in dynamic
so accordingly i need to display the pagination tab at the end of each page and display 13 items per page. Once i click on the number respective set of 13 items should be displayed.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this tutorial -> [Link](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-pagination-example-1.html)

> This task needs fair knowledge of JSTL tags, creating appropriate
>   pagination url, displaying total and numbers per page, dynamic updating of
>   records showing in each page (for example 13, 26, 39 ...), appropriate data retrieval, ETC.You need to study all those to
>   successfully implement this task. The link I sent you will help you with that.